# Ubuntu - Ruby Daemon script creates two processes - sh and ruby - PID file points at sh, not ruby

Tags: ubuntu, script, ruby

The PID file for a ruby process I have running as a daemon is getting the wrong PID.  It appears that running `/etc/init.d/sinatra start` creates two processes - `sh` and `ruby`, and the PID that ends up in the PID file is that of the `sh` process.  This means that when I then run `/etc/init.d/sinatra stop` or `/etc/init.d/sinatra restart`, it is killing sh and leaving the ruby process still running.

I'd like to know a) why is my script launching two processes - sh and ruby, and not just ruby, and b) how do I fix it to just launch ruby?

Details of the setup:

I have a small Sinatra server set up on an ubuntu server, running as a daemon.  It is set to automatically at server startup run a script named `sinatra` in `/etc/init.d` that launches the a control script `control.rb`, which then runs a ruby daemon command to start the server.  The script is run under the 'sinatrauser' account, which has permissions for the directories the script needs.

contents of /etc/init.d/sinatra

```
#!/bin/bash
# sinatra      Startup script for Sinatra server.

sudo -u sinatrauser ruby /var/www/sinatra/control.rb $1
RETVAL=$?

exit $RETVAL
```

To install this script, I simply copied it to `/etc/init.d/` and ran 
`sudo update-rc.d sinatra defaults`

contents of /var/www/sinatra/control.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'

pwd = Dir.pwd
Daemons.run_proc('sinatraserver.rb', {:dir_mode => :normal, :dir => "/opt/pids/sinatra"}) do
  Dir.chdir(pwd)
  exec 'ruby /var/www/sinatra/sintraserver.rb >> /var/log/sinatra/sinatraOutput.log 2>&1'
end
```

portion of output from ps -A

```
6967 ?         00:00:00 apache2
10181 ?        00:00:00 sh       <--- PID file gets this PID
10182 ?        00:00:02 ruby     <--- Actual ruby process running Sinatra
12172 ?        00:00:00 sshd
```

The PID file gets created in `/opt/pids/sinatra/sinatraserver.rb.pid`, and always contains the PID of the sh instance, which is always one less than the PID of the ruby process

EDIT:
I tried micke's solution, but it had no effect on the behavior I am seeing.

This is the output from `ps -A f`.  This output looks the same whether I use `sudo -u sinatrauser ...` or `su sinatrauser -c ...` in the service start script in /etc/init.d.

```
1146 ?        S      0:00 sh -c ruby /var/www/sinatra/sinatraserver.rb >> /var/log/sinatra/sinatraOutput.log 2>&1
1147 ?        S      0:00  \_ ruby /var/www/sinatra/sinatraserver.rb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form of exec that you are using is the cause of this. If you separate the command from the parameters it will avoid creating a shell. See this github issue for someone fixing a similar problem: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/pull/221.

Answer (score 1):

The first process is sudo that launches ruby. Check with `ps -A f`.
Change the sudo line to run a command.

```
su sinatrauser -c "ruby /var/www/sinatra/control.rb $1"
```

*edit*:
I think su looks neater in scripts, like this:

```
    su - someuser <<CHBACK
    ls $HOME // do stuff
    echo "do more stuff as $USER"
    CHBACK
    echo "Now I'm $USER again"
```